# how to create vnode directly inject to parent node in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

vue3 has changed its slot to **children of the current node**. basically, this is not what I want, by using

```js
h('div', { ... }, slots.default()) : null
```

it will create another div tag like this

```html
<div>
    <div>
     this is content
    </div>
</div>
```

But what I want to like this

```html
<div>
this is content
</div>
```

are there some methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `h(slots.default)` to render the default slot directly without a wrapper element (note `slots.default` is not invoked for this):

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () => h(slots.default, {/* props */}, [/* children */])
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-slot-wrapper?file=src/components/Wrapper/index.js)

Or the render function could just return `slots.default()` (assuming you don't need to modify any render properties or insert children):

```js
export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () => slots.default()
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-slot-wrapper-g73zjq?file=src/components/Wrapper/index.js)